# Interface speed is Gigabit but Circuit is 10mbs - How do I set the interface to the circuit bandwidth?

Tags: cisco, router

I have an interface that is Gigabit connecting to an interface on a carrier ATT router. The bandwidth of the ethernet circuit connecting to this interface is 10mbs. Is there a way to set the speed of the interface to match the bandwidth of the circuit?

If QoS is then applied to my gigabit interface, will it be applied and aware of the 10mb rate limit?

Comment: You have to set the "qos" traffic rate to less than the link speed. Or just let IP "figure it out" -- don't make the buffers too large in that case. Or do what I do... pass it through a slower speed port -- ISP CPE is Gig, Customer side is 100M. (which is what we pay for)

Comment: What is the command to set the traffic rate in QoS?

Comment: :-) That's why it's not an answer. I can only point to an adtran config at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
! Assign a bandwidth of 10Mbps to the interface
! This doesn't shape or police, it's just an administrative bandwidth
interface Gi0/0
 bandwidth 10000

! Create a policy-map to shape to 95% of an interface's bandwidth
! 95% to allow room for overhead or differences between your shaper and their policer
policy-map PM.WAN.OUT
 class class-default
  shape average percent 95

! Apply the policy-map to the interface in the outbound direction
! Inbound your options are policing or letting the carrier shape/police the traffic
interface Gi0/0
 service-policy output PM.WAN.OUT
```

Comment: Ok, so the policy-map does respect the assigned interface bandwidth. Thanks! In the newer ISR routers and IOS, the bandwidth command no longer exists.

Comment: The interface bandwidth command should DEFINITELY exist.  Where are you seeing it missing?

Comment: IOS 15.1 and higher for the ISR 4430 router, specifically.